# How to find Mongoose data recursively?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am newbie in MEANJS and i have a problem i.e, there are collection called `employee` and have multiple documents with their `boss` field. Now i want get all employees with their lower level.

For example:-

1) `{_id:ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd'), name:'John'} //he doesn't have boss`

2) `{_id:ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f86dddew'), name: 'Jimmy', 'boss': ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd')} //john is boss`

3) `{_id:ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f863ew'), name: 'David', 'boss': ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f86dddew')} //john,Jimmy are bosses`

4) `{_id:ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f86qwa'), name: 'Dyan', 'boss': ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f86dddew')} //john,Jimmy,David are bosses`

5) `{_id:ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f8ew32'), name:'Jack', 'boss': ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd')} //john is boss`

6) `{_id:ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f2wsw23rlot'), name: 'Loren', 'boss':ObjectId('587dcd3edca5f235f8ew32')} //john,Jack is boss`

If we take

**Jonh** then output will `['Jimmy','Jack','David','Dyan','Loren']`

**Jack** then output will `['Loren']`

Here is my try code:-

```
getBosses(user._id)
function getBosses(id){
  User.find({boss:id})
      .exec(function(err,users){
        if(err)
           return console.log(err);

        //How handle here 'users' array
       //for something getBosses call recursively


    })
}
```

Comment: [**`$graphLookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup) should do the job quite efficiently.

Comment: According to your example same boss for **David** and **Dyan** so how **David** become boss of **Dyan** ?

Comment: thanks @chridam, but it give opposite result. `aggregate([{$graphLookup: {from: "users",startWith: "$rmUserId",connectFromField: "rmUserId", connectToField: "_id", as: "rmHierarchy"}}])`, here **John** has a zero length of `rmHierarchy` array and **Loren** has all user. However i want **John** should have `rmHierarchy ['Jimmy','Jack','David','Dyan','Loren']`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need to find all subordinates of that people. I think the best way to do it is using `$graphLookup`.

```js
db.bosses.insertMany([
  { _id: "587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd", name: "John" },
  {
    _id: "587dcd3edca5f235f86dddew",
    name: "Jimmy",
    boss: "587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd",
  },
  {
    _id: "587dcd3edca5f235f863ew",
    name: "David",
    boss: "587dcd3edca5f235f86dddew",
  },
  {
    _id: "587dcd3edca5f235f86qwa",
    name: "Dyan",
    boss: "587dcd3edca5f235f86dddew",
  },
  {
    _id: "587dcd3edca5f235f8ew32",
    name: "Jack",
    boss: "587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd",
  },
  {
    _id: "587dcd3edca5f2wsw23rlot",
    name: "Loren",
    boss: "587dcd3edca5f235f8ew32",
  },
]);
```

```js
db.bosses.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "bosses",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "boss",
      as: "subordinates",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: false,
      name: true,
      subordinates: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$subordinates",
          initialValue: "",
          in: { $concat: ["$$value", ", ", "$$this.name"] },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: true,
      subordinates: { $substrBytes: ["$subordinates", 2, -1] },
    },
  },
]);
```

The result of the last one is:

```js
[
  { name: 'John', subordinates: 'David, Dyan, Loren, Jack, Jimmy' },
  { name: 'Jimmy', subordinates: 'David, Dyan' },
  { name: 'David', subordinates: '' },
  { name: 'Dyan', subordinates: '' },
  { name: 'Jack', subordinates: 'Loren' },
  { name: 'Loren', subordinates: '' }
]
```

The most important thing is `$graphLookup` stage of the aggregate pipeline. Last two `$project` stages is just response formatting - return only `name` and `subordinates` as string field with comma separated names.

To get data for a specific person you can use `$match` stage before `$graphLookup` like that:

```js
db.bosses.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: "John" } },
  {
    $graphLookup: ...
```